# do a query to get top 3 occurrences of a user_id id in rows of data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do a query where I get the top 3 contributing authors i.e. they wrote the most pages / posts.  I'd select the data by the session_id of that user associated to each row i.e. a page they wrote.  I want to select and order the top 3 people who have the most rows in the DB.  How can I query this?  I was thinking...

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM music_spot 
WHERE (need a condition here)
ORDER BY (the person who contributed the most pages to the third
LIMIT 3
```

How could I do something like this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT user_id
FROM music_spot 
WHERE session_id = 123
ORDER BY count(user_id) desc
group by user_id
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: That gets all of the user_id's.  Now how can I just get one occurrence of each id and order them by which was shows up in the most rows.  I tried DISTINCT but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(post_id)
FROM  music_spot 
GROUP BY UserID
ORDER BY COUNT(user_id) DESC
LIMIT 0,3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(row_id)
FROM  music_spot 
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(user_id) DESC
LIMIT 0,3
```